# What should be used instead of SpringBootServletInitializer deprecated in 1.4.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I've had developed the `spring-security-jsp-authorize` example. In this example I was using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.3.7.RELEASE` till that version program was not giving any deprecation error for `SpringBootServletInitializer`. What's is the replacement of `import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer` in spring-`boot-starter-parent` in version `1.4.0.RELEASE`?

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("john").password("123").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("tom").password("111").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**MvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public MvcConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
        registry.addViewController("/index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is stated in docs for Spring Boot 1.4 > `org.springframework.boot.context.web`:

> Deprecated.  as of 1.4 in favor of
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

Just change the deprecated import to this new package.

Comment: What if I don't use `Spring Boot`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebMvcConfigurer interface.

```
public class Configuration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurerconfigurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```